# Java ThreadPoolExecutor don't create new threads

Tags: java, multithreading, aem, sling

I have a servlet in AEM (Adobe Experience Manager) that create a new thread per request. I use a Apache Sling threadpool to manage the threads. All is ok, but if the servlet receives haundreds request in a few seconds the thread is not created and the threadpool is converted in useless. I have to restart the AEM instance to the threadpool The threadpool uses a queue without limit with a core pool of ten elements. The configuration is the next:

[ThreadPool configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GuNly.png)

Debuging the java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor class, my code enter into the third "if" and then not enter in the if neither the else, so, the thread is not created.

```
public void execute(Runnable command) {
    if (command == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    /*
     * Proceed in 3 steps:
     *
     * 1. If fewer than corePoolSize threads are running, try to
     * start a new thread with the given command as its first
     * task.  The call to addWorker atomically checks runState and
     * workerCount, and so prevents false alarms that would add
     * threads when it shouldn't, by returning false.
     *
     * 2. If a task can be successfully queued, then we still need
     * to double-check whether we should have added a thread
     * (because existing ones died since last checking) or that
     * the pool shut down since entry into this method. So we
     * recheck state and if necessary roll back the enqueuing if
     * stopped, or start a new thread if there are none.
     *
     * 3. If we cannot queue task, then we try to add a new
     * thread.  If it fails, we know we are shut down or saturated
     * and so reject the task.
     */
    int c = ctl.get();
    if (workerCountOf(c) < corePoolSize) {
        if (addWorker(command, true))
            return;
        c = ctl.get();
    }
    if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
        int recheck = ctl.get();
        if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
            reject(command);
        else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
            addWorker(null, false);
    }
    else if (!addWorker(command, false))
        reject(command);
}
```

I read the documentation but not understand why this occurs.

Comment: I do not have an answer to your question, but I would seriously advise you to rethink your solution using multiple threads. In all of my years working with AEM we never had to use multiple threads in a servlet. Any reason you need to create threads?

Comment: The servlet take a path parameter and launch a crawling process: I take AEM nodes recursively and put all the metadata in a Solr instance. Each node is processed by a thread

Comment: I am not sure what you requirement is. But you might be better of feeding Solr during publication. When a page or asset is published you send it's metadata to Solr.

Comment: When an asset ir published I send the metadata to Solr, but further I need a servlet to perform the operation. Checking the code, the threadpool in the servlet creates a thread that further, creates more threads in the same threadpool. This is so that the request is asynchronous. If in each case, I use distinct threadpool, the problem is solved... but I don't understand why the threads are not created if the queue haven't limits. Thanks!

Comment: With sling `ThreadPoolManager` you will have to explicitly release the thread to pool. Also if it's being rejected by executor you can provide a `RejectedExecutionHandler` and see what's happening.

Comment: Ok, I will verify the RejectedExecutionHandler but my code in the Java API don't pass to the reject method, it don't enter in the "if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))"...